# SWIG %ignore doesn't match template with typedef

Tags: c++, templates, swig

I have a templated Vector (as in a mathematical vector, not a std::vector) class which can be instantiated with a size between 2 and 4. The definition is something like:

```
template <uint32_t Size, typename StorageType>
class Vector
{
public:
  Vector(StorageType x, StorageType y);
  Vector(StorageType x, StorageType y, StorageType z);
  Vector(StorageType x, StorageType y, StorageType z, StorageType w);
  ...
};
```

In my SWIG file, I want to wrap a version which has a `Size` of `3` and a `StorageType` of `int8_t` and so I do

```
%module Vector
%{
#include "Vector.h"
%}

%include "stdint.i"
%include "Vector.h"

%ignore Vector(int8_t, int8_t);
%ignore Vector(int8_t, int8_t, int8_t, int8_t);
%template(Vector3DInt8) PolyVox::Vector<3,int8_t>;
```

But it fails to `%ignore` the requested constructors.

It seems that SWIG, inside the `%template` macro automatically 'strips off' typedefs from template parameters and so `%template(Vector3DInt8) PolyVox::Vector<3,int8_t>;` actually gets converted to `%template(Vector3DInt8) PolyVox::Vector<3,unsigned char>;`. Because of this, the `%ignore` doesn't match since `unsigned char` doesn't match `int8_t`.

If I add a `static_assert()` inside one of the functions I want to be ignored, I get:

```
source/Vector.inl: In constructor ‘Vector<Size, StorageType>::Vector(StorageType, StorageType) [with unsigned int Size = 3u, StorageType = signed char]’:
build/PolyVoxCorePYTHON_wrap.cxx:6446:100:   instantiated from here
source/Vector.inl:56:3: error: static assertion failed: "This constructor should only be used for vectors with two elements."
```

I've also tried to use `-notemplatereduce` but it seems to have no effect.

Is there a way to get SWIG to correctly ignore the unwanted constructors?

Edit: I'm using GCC 4.5 with SWIG 2.0.8

Edit 2: Added `stdint.i` to `.i` file as it is needed for Python typemaps. Without the `stdint.i`, the `%ignore` works correctly but it is needed to actually use the bindings in Python.

Comment: What version of SWIG are you using? This works exactly as you hope with 2.0.4 on my system.

Comment: SWIG 2.0.8 with GCC 4.5. If it works for you then I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: You're right that adding stdint.i stops this working. I'll dig further. (Normally in questions I'd aim to provide the smallest complete example that reproduces your problem to avoid silly things like that changing the results)