# How to make interface for std::pair<> with no default constructor in swig & python?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm going to make python wrapper using swig.
I have some classes and types in c++ dll.

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image(const Image&);
    Image& operator= (const Image&);
    ~Image();

    unsigned int width() const;
    unsigned int height() const;
};
struct Property
{
    std::string path;
    std::string datetime;
};
typedef std::pair<Image, Property> MyImage;
class Manage
{
public:
    Manage();
    ~Manage();
    void addMyImage(MyImage img);
    MyImage getMyImage(int index);
};
```

I made swig interface file following this:

```
%include "std_pair.i"
%template(MyImage) std::pair<Image, Property>;
class Image
{
public:
    Image(const Image&);
    ~Image();

    unsigned int width() const;
    unsigned int height() const;
};
class Manage
{
public:
    Manage();
    ~Manage();

    void addMyImage(std::pair<Image, Property> img);
    std::pair<Image, Property> getMyImage(int index);
};
```

I run command `swig -c++ -python Test.swig`.

I compile Test_wrapper.cxx in Visual Studio, It occurs error following this:

> error C2512: 'Image' : no appropriate default constructor available

So I tried with `swig -c++ -python -nodefaultctor Test.swig`.
But it was same.

**============UPDATE============**

The problem is `std::pair<Image, Property>`. When pair create, it calls the constructor of arguments. Image has no default constructor. So erorr occurs.

How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Well I'm stumped. I understand why nodefaultctor doesn't work I think (there's an explicit one so it isn't defaulted). I can't find any workaround that works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569939/swig-ignore-doesnt-match-template-with-typedef looks like it's pretty related too. For what it's worth questions are much easier to answer when the code you show is enough to copy and paste though - I had to add a `#include <utility>` to your C++ header and `%module %{ #include "test.hh" %}` to the SWIG interface to make them get as far as your error.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out a way to make this work. Firstly, since you've got pass-by-value semantics for `addMyImage` and `getMyImage` you need to use `%feature("valuewrapper")` to turn on pass-by-value wrapping transformation in the generated code otherwise you'll get default constructed pairs in the generated code.

Secondly you need to prevent SWIG from exposing the `std::pair` constructor that takes no arguments. (This I think is different to the `%nodefaultctor` directive because one such constructor is explicitly written and not simply assumed to exist). It took me a long time to realise the correct syntax for the easiest(?) way do do this which I believe is using advanced renaming.

So you need to add two lines before your `%include <std_pair.i>` directive:

```
%feature("valuewrapper") std::pair<Image,Property>;
%rename("$ignore",$isconstructor,fullname=1) "std::pair<(Image,Property)>";
%include "std_pair.i"
```

This does however disable all the constructors in `std::pair<Image,Property>`.

Comment: Thanks. It is great. error C2512 is fixed. But I can't use MyImage. I think it ignores all constructors of MyImage. I need a constructor to initialize MyImage with Image and Property. I just need to ignore only default constructor. How can I do it?